# .Net Core SignalR: how to persist connections

Tags: signalr, disconnect

I have an infinitely running process that pushes events from a server to subscribed SignalR clients.  There may be long periods where no events take place on the server.

Currently, the process all works fine -- for a short period of time-- but eventually, the client stops responding to events pushed by the server.  I can see the events taking place on the server-side, but the client becomes unaware of the event.  I am assuming this symptom means some timeout period has been reached and the client has unsubscribed from the Hub.

I added some code to reconnect if the connection was dropped, and that has helped, but the client still eventually stops seeing new events.  I know there are many different timeout values that can be adjusted, but it's all pretty confusing to me and not sure if I should even be tinkering with them.

```
        try
        {
            myHubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(hubURL, HttpTransportType.WebSockets)
            .AddMessagePackProtocol()
            .AddJsonProtocol(options =>
            {
                options.PayloadSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            })
            .Build();


            // Client method that can be called by server
            myHubConnection.On<string>("ReceiveInfo", json =>
            {
                // Action performed when method called by server
                pub.ShowInfo(json);
            });

            try
            {
                // connect to Hub
                await myHubConnection.StartAsync();
                msg = "Connected to Hub";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                appLog.WriteError(ex.Message);
                msg = "Error: " + ex.Message;
            }

            // Reconnect lost Hub connection
            myHubConnection.Closed += async (error) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0, 5) * 1000);
                    await myHubConnection.StartAsync();
                    msg = "Reconnected to Hub";
                    appLog.WriteWarning(msg);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    appLog.WriteError(ex.Message);
                    msg = "Error: " + ex.Message;
                }
            };
```

This all works as expected for a while, then stops without errors.  Is there something I can do to (1) ensure the client NEVER unsubscribes, and (2) if the connection is lost (network outage for example) ensures the client resubscribes to the events.  This client must NEVER timeout or give up trying to reconnect if required.

Comment: I should mention the client is .Net Framework 4.7.1(Windows service) and the server is .Net Core 2.2.

Comment: Should I dump SignalR completely?  Looking urgently for some help

Comment: Have I given insufficient information to get an answer?  Why am I not getting any responses?  What more do you need to be able to offer suggestions?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with the technology you're needing, but I came across your comment. Your question has only been visited 13 times, that's not a lot and could be the problem. You can try to add a more general tag to get more eyes on your it.